# Problems with the definition of an entity in ER diagram

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have to build the conceptual model for a school, which has a Cafe inside it. The school wants to control the profits which derive from the Cafe.

What could be the best way to represent this with an er-diagram?

I tried to create the entity **"CAFE"**, with attributes **NameActivity**, Profits. But I don't think that makes sense

Comment: ' I don't know if that makes sense' - not to me , where does profits come from? It seems likely that every activity generates expense and income and profit is the difference

Comment: @P.Salmon The fact is that this DBMS is concentrated on other points (STUDENTS, CLASS,TEACHERS...) This of the Cafe is "another thing". The User at the end of his request adds that he also wants to track the profits of the Cafe, but I don't know which could be the easiest way to do that without creating a bunch of other entities

Comment: An ERD is but one tool to help you design a system. You seem to have skipped over the analysis phase of "what does this system do and how will it be used" to designing the database. Profits are the last thing you need to worry about because it depends on the actual business of buying, selling, making, paying, etc. So walk through the process of starting a cafe. What things do you need to get to open for business? On day one of actual business, what things do you need to record as customers purchase?

Comment: @SMor That's clear, I took you suggestion and added the entity "ORDER" , in relationship with the entity "STUDENTS". Since we are talking about a Cafe, you'd say that each order can be taken by a single student (1:M) or each order can be taken by one ore more students (for example with a single receipt 3 students buy 3 coffees) ? – Jenny 25 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

One possible conceptual model could be this

[image: ER Diagram]

The Cafe generates orders and every orders contains different order rows (cappuccino, latte, and so on). You can retrive the profit simply adding the cost of each order row.

Comment: Thank you" but in this case, which could be the identifier of "Cafe"?

Comment: If there are more than one "Cafe" in your schoole you can use a simple ID field set as primary key. If there is only one "Cafe" you can easily remove entity "Cafe" and relation "Generate" and only track the order.

Comment: Thanks! Since we are talking about a Cafe, you'd say that each order can be taken by a single student (1:M) or each order can be taken by one ore more students (for example with a single receipt 3 students buy 3 coffees) ?

Comment: (In this case M:N)

Comment: if an order can be taken by a single student or a group of students is a requirement of the problem. If you are free to choose, I will suggest to use a 1:M relation (an order is taken by a single student) which I consider a simpler solution.

Comment: It is not specified, so yes I can choose, but I have to choose the most realistic scenario since I have to justify my choice, and so explain in this case why I opted for 1:M. What can I say in this case? That each order can be taken just by a single scholar because .....[?] ?

Comment: ...because this is the most common behavior in a real cafe: one customer goes to the checkout and pays whatever he had ordered.